# How to create a IPA file for iphone app?

Tags: iphone

I have created a iphone app. Everything working well in simulator. I want to test it in device. Provisioning profile or certificates are created and just need to create IPA file.
Please tell me step by step how to do that, if somebody knows it well.I am searching google but not find satisfying result. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=d4f7d769c2abecc664d0dadfed6a67f943442b5e9c87524d4587a95773750cea&path=//ios/manage/distribution/index.action) may help you out for step by step process of making ipa.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to get .ipa file from Xcode:

1. Select correct provisioning profile in Project and Targets -> Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Code Signing Identity
2. In Targets change the Bundle Identifier by Targets -> Info -> Bundle Identifier
3. Clean your project
4. Archive your project by Product -> Archive
5. Organizer automatically open with separate window there you can see you project with Archive date/time and project name
6. Click Share button from the Organizer window
7. It will ask to you choose the correct Provisioning profile do this correctly
8. It will ask you for the location to store, select Desktop or anywhere else
9. In your selected location the project .ipa file will be stored

Please do the above steps. I hope you got some idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an IPA is done along the same way as creating an .xcarchive: Product -> Archive. After the Archive operation completes, go to the Organizer, select your archive, select Share and in the "Select the content and options for sharing:" pane set Contents to "iOS App Store Package (.ipa) and Identity to iPhone Distribution (which should match your ad hoc/app store provisioning profile for the project).

Chances are the "iOS App Store Package (.ipa)" option may be disabled. This happens when your build produces more than a single target: say, an app and a library. All of them end up in the build products folder and Xcode gets naïvely confused about how to package them both into an .ipa file, so it merely disables the option.

A way to solve this is as follows: go through build settings for each of the targets, except the application target, and set Skip Install flag to YES. Then do the Product -> Archive tango once again and go to the Organizer to select your new archive. Now, when clicking on the Share button, the .ipa option should be enabled.

I hope this helps.

Comment: first set running environment to device (instead of simulator) -> product -> Archive , now if you getting any error then setup provision  profile..